# Linux Suspend To RAM from idle loop

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded, suspend

I have a question regarding STR (Suspend To RAM) in the Linux kernel.

I am working on a small embedded Linux (Kernel 3.4.22) and I want to implement a mechanism that will put the system into sleep (suspend to ram) while it has nothing to do.

This is done in order to save power.

The HW support RAM self-refresh meaning its content will stay persistence. 
And I'll take care of all the rest things which should be done (e.g keeping CPU context etc…)

I want to trigger the Kernel PM (power management) subsystem from within the idle loop.
When the system has nothing to do, it should go into sleep.

The HW also supports a way to wake up the system.

Doing some research, I have found out that Linux gives an option for the user space to switch to STR by writing "echo "mem" > /sys/power/state".
This will trigger the PM subsystem and will perform the relevant callbacks.

My questions are:
Is there any other standard alternative to go into STR besides writing to the above proc?

Did anyone tried to put the system into STR from the idle loop code ?

Thanks,

Comment: That is a standard way as far as I know. But hey, you perhaps has to consider using runtime PM.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need another method? Linux treats everything as a file. Is it any surprise that the contents of a psudo-file dictate the state of the system? Check for yourself. pm-utils is a popular tool set for managing the state of the system. All the commands are just calls to /sys files.

Comment: The thing is that I want to trigger it from the Kernel idle loop. I tried to do the same as the sysfs write callback but this cannt be done since the PM calls to sync which requires context switching. so I was wondering if there are other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

This policy is actually platform dependent. You would have to look at the cpuidle driver for your platform to understand what it is doing. For example, on atmel platforms, it is using both RAM self refresh and WFI.